# Setting up sample project for other developers Xcode

Tags: xcode

So I am trying to set up a sample project that includes all of the search headers for distributing to other developers.

My plan is to have the folder structure something like this when the developer unzips the project:

/SDKandSample

/SDKandSample/SDK

/SDKandSample/SampleProject

How can I have xcode link to the correct SDK folder regardless of where the folder is stored?

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a workspace that includes two projects. One project is your framework / library. And the other is your example project. The example project will link to your framework / library. Check out [this project](https://github.com/alfiehanssen/gifset) for an example.

If you're wondering how to create file paths in build settings that reference the project root:

`$(SRCROOT)/MyDirectory/MyFile.ext`